# VoyageMongo: is it OK to override #= in persistent classes?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm having an issue with VoyageMongo. I'm getting duplicated objects when *editing* them (i.e. altering and saving already persisted objects), specifically with those that override `#=` and `#hash`.

Here's the (simplified) case: I have the `UserAccount` class, with instance vars `email`, `salt` (for password encryption) and `name`. These are the `#=` and `#hash` methods:

```
= anObject
    (self isKindOf: anObject class)
        ifFalse: [ ^ false ].
    ^ self email = anObject email and: [ self salt = anObject salt ]

hash
    ^ (self salt hash + self email hash) hash
```

`email` and `salt` are set at creation and never change. Now, here's a little script:

```
UserAccount removeAll.
20 timesRepeat: [ UserAccount new save ].
10 timesRepeat: [ UserAccount selectAll atRandom
            name: 'Joe Doe';
            save ].
UserAccount selectAll size = 20
```

This generates 20 `UserAccount`s (`#new` creates an instance with random email and salt in this case), then picks 10 at random and edits their names. The final size of `UserAccount selectAll` **should stay at 20, but it is usually larger**, meaning it's storing duplicates.

**Possible culprit:** debugging into `VOCache`, the `WeakKeyDictionary` holding the cached objects (in `reversedObjects` var, where objects themselves are the keys) sometimes fails to "hit" existing object, since the `#scanFor:` starts looking at different points (more specifically, `#startIndexFor:`) as the keys array grows larger. When this happens, I can see the object inside `VOCache`'s `reversedObjects` but `VOCache>>keyAtValue:` fails to find it.

Long story short:

- is it that I shouldn't override `#=` in persistent objects? Or...
- is it that my `#hash` is not well implemented?

Or, of course, any other issue I'm not seeing :)

Thanks a lot!

PS: tested this in Pharo 6.1 and 7 with latest VoyageMongo.

Comment: The method `keyAtValue:` doesn't use the `#hash` (it is the keys, not to values, which get hashed in a `Dictionary`.) So, it can't be the `#hash` method. If you see the object in the cache, `keyAtValue:` should find it (unless `#=` is broken, which doesn't seem to be in your case)

Comment: Thanks Leandro. The non-intuitive issue here is that the i.v. ```reversedObjects``` is a ```WeakKeyDictionary``` in which the **objects are the keys** (will edit the question to clarify).So, ```VOCache>>keyAtValue:``` calls ```WeakKeyDictionary>>#at:ifAbsent:```, which calls ```#findElementOrNil:``` then ```#scanFor:``` and finally ```#startIndexFor:``` (uff :)) where ```#hash:``` is used to scan the internal array of keys.

Comment: I see. In the code you included in the question, there is no indication that changing the `name` will change the `hash` because the hash relies on the `email`. Could you confirm this? In other words, could you confirm that after changing the `name` the hash remains the same?

Comment: Wait a minute!! If you change the `#hash` method (which you did when reimplementing it) you must rehash the `WeekKeyDictionary`. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, actually I ran the tests with a brand new cache each time, trying to isolate the case as much as possible. Regarding the other question, I took care of only using immutable attributes for ```#=``` and ```#hash``` (i.e. set at creation and never changed). It's hardly an issue with ```WeakKeyDictionary``` (there must be something I don't understand about the keys' lookup) because it is widely used across the system, so perhaps it's an issue with how ```VOCache``` uses it.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you shouldn't override the #= and #hash in entity objects as these need to be based on identity vs on value.

If 2 objects match on the values of their parameters then this does not necessarily mean they represent the same entity; if you really need to override the #= then you will need a *business key*. 
Best to simply not override and just use entity objects based on identity when you pull them from the DB. i.e. as if you're working with an OO DB.

Perhaps this is a Voyage bug as the **reversedObjects** variable should be a WeakIdentityKeyDictionary?

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this general rule about persistent objects. The thing is I **was** using a _business key_, and following all the rules about ```#=``` and ```#hash``` redefinition, so my concern was about the cache, since the identity-based ```#hash``` worked and my overridden version didn't. Will follow your lead on the potential bug and report back!